# Calculating the range of column value datewise through Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, date-difference

[image]

I want to calculate the maximum difference of `product_mrp` according to the dates. 
For that I was trying to group by date but not able to get after that.

INPUT:

```
+-------------+--------------------+
| product_mrp |     order_date     |
+-------------+--------------------+
|         142 |         01-12-2019 |
|          20 |         01-12-2019 |
|          20 |         01-12-2019 |
|         120 |         01-12-2019 |
|          30 |         03-12-2019 |
|          20 |         03-12-2019 |
|          45 |         03-12-2019 |
|         215 |         03-12-2019 |
|          15 |         03-12-2019 |
|          25 |         07-12-2019 |
|           5 |         07-12-2019 |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
 +-------------+--------------------+
| product_mrp |     order_date     |
+-------------+--------------------+
|         122 |         01-12-2019 |
|         200 |         03-12-2019 |
|          20 |         07-12-2019 |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas` to load the data, then use `groupby` to group by the shared index:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['01-12-2019']*4 + ['03-12-2019']*5 + ['07-12-2019']*2
data = [142,20,20,120,30,20,45,215,15,25,5]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(dates)

grouped = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

Output:

```
            product mrp
2019-01-12          122
2019-03-12          200
2019-07-12           20
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `groupby` as you said and `max`, `min` and `reset_index` like:

```
gr = df.groupby('order_date')['product_mrp']
df_ = (gr.max()-gr.min()).reset_index()

print (df_)
   order_date  product_mrp
0  01-12-2019          122
1  03-12-2019          200
2  07-12-2019           20
```